# Change color of a cell whose value got through getCellByColumnAndRow

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I got a cell whose value is "Duplicate" through getCellByColumnAndRow() in phpspreadsheet.
Now How can I change cell color.
 `$sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getFill();`

Answer (score 0):

For the cell background (fill) color, do something like:

```
$cell->getStyle()
     ->getFill()
     ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
     ->setStartColor('Red');
```

For the font color, try:

```
$cell->getStyle()
     ->getFont()
     ->setColor('White');
```

See the Style class for further info:

https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/classes/PhpOffice-PhpSpreadsheet-Style-Style.html